# ClosedXML - Is there any way where I can show auto filter for only few columns and not all columns in a worksheet?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, closedxml

I am trying to use SetAutoFIlter() but it is not giving me any such option

Comment: I would suggest first - ignoring the programming side of things - are you able to achieve what you're asking for via the Excel UI? If so, it may be worth adding those steps so that others can see what you're trying to achieve. If not, it may indicate that it's not possible *at all*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  Yeah You are right. It seems we can not do that in Excel itself. Maybe its not possible then.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve. Please could you provide some clarity with example of expected output. I believe you want to add the Auto Filter row for only some columns, which can be achieved by doing something like this. `worksheet.Column("A").SetAutoFilter()`

Comment: Show us your current code. See Stackoverflow.com recommendations for how to ask a question.